# pandas.Series.map depending on order of items in dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to map the data types of a pandas DataFrame to different names using the map method. It works for 2 out of 3 permutations of the data types within the dictionary argument to map. But the 3rd one is ignoring 'int64'. Is the order of the dictionary keys supposed to matter or what am I missing here?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1,2,3],
    'y': [1.0, 2.2, 3.5],
    'z': ['one', 'two', 'three']
})

df.dtypes

df.dtypes.map({'int64': 'integer', 'float64': 'decimal', 'object': 'character'}) # works
df.dtypes.map({'object': 'character', 'float64': 'decimal', 'int64': 'integer'}) # works
df.dtypes.map({'float64': 'decimal', 'int64': 'integer', 'object': 'character'}) # NaN for x
```

Comment: What's your end goal here?

Comment: compare it with the types the columns are supposed to have, which are named differently and avoid future mistakes due to not fully understanding how map works.

Comment: Are you attempting to convert the z variable into an int64 dtype?

Comment: No. I just want to get a renamed version of the data types for each column. Why is x, which is int64 and therefore in the dictionary keys, ignored in the last line?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by a "renamed" version?

Comment: a version where int64 is named integer etc. The 2 lines with "works" as comment at the end do exactly what I want, but why doesn't the 3rd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data in the Series returned by `dtypes` is not of type `str` but rather `dtype`, which seems to cause non-deterministic behavior in `map` when it is passed a dict with keys of type `str`.

A way to clear this up is to use `astype(str)` on `dtypes`:

```python
print( df.dtypes.astype(str).map({'int64': 'integer', 'float64': 'decimal', 'object': 'character'}) )
print( df.dtypes.astype(str).map({'object': 'character', 'float64': 'decimal', 'int64': 'integer'}) )
print( df.dtypes.astype(str).map({'float64': 'decimal', 'int64': 'integer', 'object': 'character'}) )
```

Output:

```
x      integer
y      decimal
z    character
dtype: object
x      integer
y      decimal
z    character
dtype: object
x      integer
y      decimal
z    character
dtype: object
```